# Is the Galois group of a Galois cover an actual Galois group of a field extension?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, covering-spaces

My question will probably sound extremely naive to people who knows something of this theory, but I'm starting to learn small bits of this extremely general machinery and I'm lost in finding suitable references for my interests.

I've read that we can translate a lot from the theory of covering spaces to the algebro-geometric setting. Suppose to have a scheme $X$ over a field $k$ and $Y\to X$ is a finite and étale cover, that is a finite morphism of schemes such that the preimages of an affine cover $X=\bigcup\mathrm{Spec}(A_i)$ are of the form $\mathrm{Spec}(B_i)$ with $A_i\to B_i$ defining a (finite) free and separable $A_i$-algebra structure on $B_i$. Then, such a morphism is said to be a Galois covering if the group $\mathrm{Aut}_X(Y)$ of the automorphisms of $Y$ over $X$ (the automorphism of $Y$ in the category $\textbf{Sch}/X$) acts transitively on the fiber of each generic point. In this case, I saw this group denoted by $\mathrm{Gal}(Y/X)$.

So, question. Is this group, in the case of a Galois cover, the Galois group of some (normal and separable) extension - maybe - of the ground field $k$? If so, of which one? If not, how does the Galois group of a field extension of $k$ appear in this context?

Thanks in advance, I hope the question is not too vague. Inputs of different kind and references are appreciated :)

Comment: It might help you to translate to a more concrete example.  Say you are trying to find rational points on a (sufficiently interesting) variety.  This variety is a geometrical object in (affine or projective) space and has a covering space -- this fact is independent of what kinds of points we are trying to find.  We can extend the field of acceptable points, say to $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$; this does not change the geometry of the variety.

Comment: I recall that in the case of algebraic curves over $\mathbb{C}$, (compact Riemann surfaces) any holomorphic map $Y\rightarrow X$ is like a (ramified) covering, and by pullback gives rise to a field extension $K_X \rightarrow K_Y$, where the $K$s are fields of regular (meromorphic) functions on the surfaces. I don't know if the group of automorphisms of the covering is the same as the Galois group of the field, but this may be the closest thing I know to what you are talking about.

Comment: You should think about it more as a generalization. Galois groups in the usual sense are special cases of this setup.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. @CaptainLama what you say is very interesting and probably what I'm trying to understand, could you please expand a little? What are the special cases giving this result?

Comment: The case where $X$ and $Y$ are spectra of fields. In that case the cover corresponds to a (finite separable) field extension, and the automorphisms of the cover are the automorphisms of the extension (ie the Galois group).

Comment: Oh that makes sense indeed, cause we're taking ring automorphisms fixing the ground field, thank you!

Comment: @CaptainLama Sorry to bother you, but do you have a suggestion for reference on this subject? Especially, I'd like to understand how further this generalizartion can be carried on. For example, does the subgroup of the Galois group of a Galois cover classify something?

Comment: I think Szamuely's "Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups" is fairly good. It is not really a beginner's book though, but you can see if it fits you.